How should I connect new wire to an older metal outlet box?
I’m trying to move and upgrade an older 20 amp GFCI kitchen outlet box. It has to move. It is currently mounted only slightly above an electric range which I think, poses a potential fire hazard.
I own the condo apartment.
As I understand the current wiring arrangement, this load-only connection is intended to protect other outlets on the
kitchen circuit.
Additionally, I want to add a 12/20 amp wire and outlet to supply power to a smart oven located about 3 feet away. Please note that the 120 volt switch to the right is/was for an antiquated exhaust wall fan which will be removed. So far as I can determine, it is not connected to the GFCI outlet.
I’m also replacing the GFCI outlet as well.
My question is basically this: How should I safely connect the new wire/outlet to the new box?


That's assuming you don't own the condo.

I've managed to fix one of your pics, but you've managed to murder all the others ...

Electrical work in buildings with other people/families have extra regulations than single detached houses owned by the one living there.  Check with your local building department before even touching it.   You make an oops and you are responsible for everybody else damage and your insurance will not cover it.  By condo, I am assuming other condos/apartments are attached to yours, not single family house.

Please revise your post to properly add any images that are missing. I've updated your title to ask a clear question, but it may not be what you intended. Revise that also as needed. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Rather than literally "move" the electrical box, it's normally much more practical to leave the current box in place, covered with a blank faceplate, and run cable from it to a new box. Could you clarify where you want your new box, as well as show the wiring inside the old box?

Other option: get an induction range?

Is the presumed fire hazard due to potential splashes of cooking liquid?  Isn't that what a GFCI is for, though?
